# Line break in API consumption

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, nuxt.js

I'm working on a project using nuxtJS and a REST API(Json) made with laravel.

I have a simple blog system, have a title, thumbnail and body, which would be the text

But I have a problem when displaying the text to the user, for example

at the time of writing the text in the dashboard, I use a text with a line break

```
Line 1.

Line 2.
```

When I consume the API and return this to user, it gets no line break,

```
Line 1.Line2.
```

when I use this function in php, to return the body

```
$blog->body = nl2br($blog->body);
```

So I get a text like this in my final result

```
Line 1.<br /> <br /> Line2.
```

With tag **br**, but not breaking yes, but as text literally

Someone to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to display raw html use [v-html directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML). But since its a blog you really need to sanitize your html against white list.

> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very
> dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities. Only use
> HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided
> content.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: and if I'm using the v-model directive, how do I use v-html?

<textarea v-model = "form.body"> </ textarea>

Comment: @YungSilva your question doesnt make much sense. v-html is for displaying html. v-model for changing it. You cant display html inside text-area, because textarea display plain text, not an html